# Proxy postgres server

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, odbc

Im using an application that can communicate with Postgres, but can not add custom odbc/jdbc drivers. I need it to connect to my custom source which has a custom driver I can download.

Is there a simple middleman/proxy application that can expose a ‘Postgres’ database for my application to connect to, by allowing me to use the custom driver?

Comment: You absolutely can connect to postgres using odbc/jdbc... I must be misunderstanding the question

Comment: I want to connect my application to some middle application that provides a Postgres endpoint, but Sources data from custom databases using whatever odbc/jdbc driver I give it.

Comment: ODBC/Jdbc drivers are specific.You can use a connection pooler if you're just wanting a "middle point" but they all have their own drivers I'm sure.

What driver would you be using? You say "Custom"... but is this driver Postgres compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to talk PostgreSQL line protocol but access some other data source that way.

For that, you should use foreign data wrappers. Then you would connect to a real PostgreSQL database, and the external data source would be made available as a PostgreSQL table through a foreign data wrapper for that data source.

PostgreSQL is shipped with a foreign data wrapper that can access CSV files as PostgreSQL tables, but [there are many foreign data wrappers out there](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fdw) for various data sources.

Comment: Ty I’ll take a look at that approach, but the custom data source I need to connect to provides a jdbc driver, and odbc driver that can be downloaded. I believe this is different than a foreign data wrapper. Is there a way to do this using the drivers they provide..? Or would that theoretically be the same?

Comment: There are FDWs for ODBC and JDBC. I don't know how well they work. There just isn't any other translator between the PostgreSQL protocol and other protocols. I think you should port your client code from PostgreSQL to whatever else you have.